# Computer beeping with new CPU (won't start)

Tags: memory, cpu

I tried upgrading my processor but when I boot it gives me 1 short + 1 long beep (repeating on a black/blank screen). Which would be a memory problem according to the manual. Nothing wrong with my memory tho(?). When I put the old processor back; everything works fine.

This is my computer: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/435619/Hp-Pro-3120-Minitower-Pc.html?page=2#manual

I upgraded from **E5500, 2-MB cache, 2.80 GHz** to **Q8400, 4-MB cache, 2.66 GHz**

New thermal paste between changes and all that. The fan doesn't seem to run any faster than usual when I try to boot with the new processor.

I have 8gb RAM, Windows 7 64-bit. Hope I got all the info required down. I was really looking forward to this upgrade - now I'm just a sad panda. Hopefully someone can help?

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION: So apparently this was a memory issue - the new cpu booted with one of my sticks (http://www.electrobyt.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=6129#.VpD5BFLlnyF) and that one only. No other combinations or singles of my sticks worked. I even tried different dimm-slots for everything.

Comment: Did you upgrade the BIOS to the latest version before installing the new(er) processor? If not, go try that and report back. :)

Comment: CPU has memory on die. The bios will qualify all memory in the system at startup.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `memory` when it has nothing to do with `memory`?

Comment: The processor your trying to upgrade to isn't supported by your hardware.  Your new processor requires 30 additional watts in order to function.  What made you think it was compatible?

Comment: @Ramhound its listed in the link they posted, as well in the official HP pdf for that model.  http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=4191679&spf_p.tpst=psiContentResults&spf_p.prp_psiContentResults=wsrp-navigationalState%3Daction%253Dmanualslist%257Ccontentid%253DService-and-maintenance%257Clang%253Den&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: Can you link to the exact processor you bought?

Comment: @Moab Don't really know what that means - but is there a solution for that?

Comment: @Ramhound Having a bad day? It's tagged with memory because of the beeping code and as Moab said; it's listed as supported.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete http://ark.intel.com/sv/products/38512/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8400-4M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB

Comment: @eskilla - Nope; Having a wonderful suburb day.  I asked a question

Comment: Make sure you have the latest BIOS, as suggested above. Did you connect the CPU heatsink and fan when you tested with the new CPU?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I can't find a newer BIOS version than I'm currently running (American Megatrends Inc. 6.09, 2012-01-16).

Comment: @Ramhound well maybe if you read the question properly you wouldn't have to have asked an annoying and pointless question in return.

Comment: @Ramhound and maybe you couldn't have been more wrong on everything you wrote here haha! I quote "Why is this tagged with memory when it has nothing to do with memory" - seeeeems like memory was a very correct tag after all? And where did you get the "30 additional watts in order to function" from? Thin air? Don't pull "advices" (or w/e you wanna call that bs) from your behind. Now, go have a good day and try not to be so condescending - as you can see; it backfires.

Comment: This pdf says use PC2 10600 memory not PC3...http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=4191679&spf_p.tpst=psiContentResults&spf_p.prp_psiContentResults=wsrp-navigationalState%3Daction%253Dmanualslist%257Ccontentid%253DService-and-maintenance%257Clang%253Den&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: @Moab But a PC3-8500 (1066MHz) memory is the only one making the new CPU boot. What's up with that?

Comment: Dunno, just reading the documentation, sorry.